# Cannot get Microfocus Visual Cobol Personal Edition to install on Windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, cobol

I have spent the better part of 3 days trying to get this package to install. The jist of my problem is that the installer can't find a java on my machine.  It keeps failing telling me that the product needs an Oracle Java of at least 1.6.0 and restart the installation when one is installed.

Let me describe my problem:

Windows 7 64bit
Java Oracle 1.7.0_04 (this was installed into the (x86) folder so I am assuming that this is the 32bit version.

The current version of Visual Cobol runs with Eclipse. They supply a 32bit Visual Cobol and a 32bit Eclipse.  The installation instructions say I must install a 32bit Java for installation.

Here is my JAVA_HOME:
  c:\program files(x86)\java\jdk1.7.0_04

Here is my JRE_HOME:
  c:\program files (x86)\java\jre7

Here is my PATH:
 .;c:\program files(x86)\java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ibm\gsk8\lib64;C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\gsk8\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\FUNCTION;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\SAMPLES\REPL;c:\program files\ibm\sqllib\java\bin;c:\program files\ibm\sqllib\lib;

It must be something with the Environment Variables, but for the life of me I can't find the problem.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try installing a 32 bit Java JRE to some other directory besides Program Files (x86),  Install to C:/Java.

Answer (score 1):

I copy paste the variable value as you wrote it to us:

```
JAVA_HOME: c:\program files(x86)\java\jdk1.7.0_04
```

Notice there's no space before (x86). Should be:

> c:\program files (x86)\java\jdk1.7.0_04

Microsoft's choice to name a critical system folder that way is quite silly...

Comment: Comments are restricted to 50 reputation to limit SPAM in comments. Anyway, a bit further towards 50 for you.

Comment: @BillWoodger Thanks :) 
If I wanted to have a score of 1000-2000, I can easily do that.
All I need to do is ask a really simple question. Such that I am supposed to google and get on the first hit.
I'll have 200-300 ups and 10-20 answers in the first 10 minutes...

But if I want to actually answer, I can't do that on a 0-score... They assume whoever is a new user has no worthwhile knowledge to share and must be in here just for asking questions.

end-rant
.

Comment: That strategy wouldn't work these days, mostly :-) You can always answer. Even an unregistered user can answer. The moderation tools are much better for questions and answers than the almost non-existent tools for comments, so the harsher limit. There's a recent discussion on this on meta.stackoverflow, if I can find it. It isn't a good situation, but it isn't easy to make it better.

Comment: I found the post. Still not happy. I want my money back! ;)